# Setting time out for NSMutableURLRequest to custom time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutableurlrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSMutableURLRequest timeout doesn't trigger if data starts to load but not webViewDidFinishLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883888/nsmutableurlrequest-timeout-doesnt-trigger-if-data-starts-to-load-but-not-webvie)

I am using a Async HTTP request and setting timeout for my NSMutableURLRequest to 30 seconds and I want to timeout the request within this time.

Problem: Request is not getting timed out withing 30 seconds. It is always taking 90 seconds to timeout. Any solution for this.

Here is my code for connection:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];
[myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[myRequest setHTTPBody:myData];

NSURLConnection *myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];
```

And I am implementing following delgates:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)iConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)iResponse;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)iConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)iElementContructionContextData;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)iConnection didFailWithError:(NSError *)iError;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set your time for timeOutSeconds  like this:-

```
[myRequest setTimeOutSeconds:1000];
```

Set timeOutSecond according to yourself.