# Get parameters from a link in a webview

Tags: ios, webview, swift3, permalinks

I have created a webview in a viewController and loading a page like this

```
func loadAddress(){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"http://www.example.com/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as! URL)
    webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
}
```

And calling this in

> viewDidLoad

I have somelinks in the page with URL parameters like this

```
http://www.example.com?id=1&title=ABC
```

Now when a user clicks this link from the app then instead of redirecting to URL, I want to get the parameters from URL and open a dialog box in iOS

I have found some examples in Objective C but I am looking for a solution in Swift 3

PS: I have access to this website's HTML I can replace links as required by Xcode

EDIT: Here is what i have tried, in the same file where my webview is i wrote this function

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView,shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest,navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let scheme = request.url!
    NSLog(scheme.absoluteString)

    return false

}
```

and also made sure that the class is a delegate to webview

[image]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but please note that you should not downcast NSURL to URL or NSURLRequest to URLRequest, [just use the new structs directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet/37812485#37812485).

Comment: xcode was giving errors and suggested this fix by itself

Comment: Probably, but it's irrelevant. Xcode is just an IDE, it's not always right. Actually, sometimes, it's plain wrong... ;) TL;DR: don't downcast when you don't have to, whatever Xcode tells you.

Answer (score 0):

you should handle the `webView(_ webView: UIWebView, 
  shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, 
       navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` method, that takes the URLRequest as a parameter.
In this method you can do whatever you want to that URL.

Don't forget to set your class as the delegate of the webview.

If you want to play with the query string, you can get inspiration from this [objective-c answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997976/parse-nsurl-query-property)

Comment: under this function i have my code looks like this, let scheme = request.url!
        NSLog(scheme.path)
        
        return true

Comment: and class is a delegate of webview, but nothing prints in log when i click the link

Comment: what if you write NSLog(scheme.absoluteSring) ?

Comment: and just a question, why do you call the NSURL "scheme"? and not some url name?

Comment: i have updated the question with what you have suggested, please check

Comment: i found this help from somewhere i just copy pasted the "scheme" thing

Comment: @WasifKhalil what does NSLog(scheme.absoluteString) print?

Comment: it prints nothing in the log, looks like the function is not even calling

Comment: the NSLog? try to put some string before scheme.absoluteURL

Comment: i tried NSLog("WORKING: "+scheme.absoluteString) but nothing in the log, it seems like the function is not calling

Comment: my viewcontroller where the webview is, is inside a TabbarController, does it affect anything?

Comment: No, just make sure the viewcontroller is the delegate of the webview

Comment: yes it is delegate, because i have webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad to show and hide the UIActivityIndicatorView, which is working fine

Comment: @WasifKhalil so remove shouldStartLoadWithRequest and rewrite it again, use autocompletion for this ;) please update me if it's ok

Comment: it didnt work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389612/dispatch-async-uiwebview-loadrequest just wondering why some people using dispatch_async? does it affect anything

Comment: i have found the solution :) going to post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself, the code i had written was correct, i just had to make sure that my class also implements UIWebViewDelegate

so the class looks like this

```
class Mainbillboard: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    loadAddress()
}

func loadAddress(){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"example.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as! URL)
    webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)

}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let scheme = request.url!
    NSLog(scheme.absoluteString)
    NSLog("here it worked!!")

    return true

}


func webViewDidStartLoad(_:UIWebView){
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.activity)
    activity.startAnimating()
    NSLog("Indicator is loading")

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_:UIWebView){
    activity.stopAnimating()
    NSLog("Indicator stopped loading")
}

}
```