# iOS UIWebView keeps showing timeout error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, timeout

So I'm working on an app using UIWebView

And there is a js function which calls the webview to set data and the page to load it
The page loads it and takes around 23sec to process in android (yeah it takes pretty long..)
The problem is, in ios, an error keeps showing and the loading fails after every 10 secs...
(I've set every connection timeout at 30 sec as i can)

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
> (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
> failed to return after waiting 10.000000 seconds. main run loop mode:
> kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Does anybody know how to fix it?
I'm using objective C

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615699/ios-app-set-timeout-for-uiwebview-loading ?